# How to determine the amount of n possibilities of a word?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am defining a word by a `n` character sequence.

In English (for the purposes of my paper), I am assuming the following:

- The alphabet is only the 26 characters alpha characters, lowercased
- Digits are only 0-9 (10 total)
- A space is allowed

Therefore, how many `5-n` combinations can I have?

I believe this is a `[combinatorial][1]` problem but I haven't really found any resources that would give me a way to attack this problem (that I can understand).

I did find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176538/how-to-find-number-of-combinations) which would make me think:

I need to do something like: `26 * 10 * 1 * 5!` but I don't think that is right.
Where `26, 10, 1` all represent the possibilities of inputs and `5!` is the size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a famous combinatorics formula defined as $\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n - r)!}$

For your problem, you have 37 distinct characters, and you want to know the amount of combinations that can be made of these characters where each combination has a length of 5. To use the formula, we let $n = 37$ and $r = 5$.

Simply, apply these numbers in the given formula.

$\binom{37}{5} = \frac{37!}{5! * (37 - 5)!} = 435897$